# Stop WCF MessageInspector from automatically encoding message to Base64String

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, arrays, base64

I have a class MessageInspector that implemenents [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx), and in its BeforeSendReply method I intercept all WCF replies so I can compress the data before the message gets sent. The data is a ByteArray.

The problem is that when I re-construct the message with the compressed ByteArray, WCF encodes the message as a Base64String and then sends it off, is there any way to disable this automatic encoding?

Code:

```
public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    if (!reply.IsFault && !reply.IsEmpty)
    {
        //read json
        XmlDictionaryReader bodyReader = reply.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlDictionaryWriter jsonWriter = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(ms);
        jsonWriter.WriteNode(bodyReader, true);
        jsonWriter.Flush();

        //compress data
        byte[] ba = ms.ToArray();
        byte[] data = ZLibCompressor.Compress(ba);

        //rebuild and send reply
        Message newReply = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, null, data);
        reply = newReply;
    }
}
```

Reply in browser:

[image: WCF Get reply in Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

Answers possibly here:

[Getting around base64 encoding with WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063595/getting-around-base64-encoding-with-wcf)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/c32a34c3-dfda-4c54-ab13-fd595fb883ab

And look at this one...you might be able to write the message as binary using CreateBinaryWriter.

[Sending custom WCF Message to a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809084/sending-custom-wcf-message-to-a-service)

http://www.techbubbles.com/webservices/wcf-service-using-mtom-in-net-fw-4/

Comment: MTOM looks interesting, I'll check it out. Thanks!